# Mail won't start up after migration to Mountain Lion Server

Tags: postfix, mac-osx-server, migration, osx-mountain-lion

I'm not sure where to start. Our hard disk died on server running 10.6.8. Installed new disk. Followed Apple's migration instructions to 10.8.2. All services are operational except Mail.

```
Dec  7 10:04:46 server.mydomain.com servermgrd[118]: Error: Status Check: SMTP mail service is enabled but not running
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify' by client '/usr/libexec/launchdadd' [901] for authorization created by '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] (100002,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com postfix/master[906]: fatal: bind: private/smtp: Permission denied
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify' by client '/usr/libexec/launchdadd' [901] for authorization created by '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] (100002,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [117] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [117] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [117] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:48 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:49 server com.apple.launchd[1] (org.postfix.master[906]): Exited with code: 1
Dec  7 10:04:49 server com.apple.launchd[1] (org.postfix.master): Throttling respawn: Will start in 9 seconds
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com postfix/postfix-script[912]: fatal: no Postfix queue directory /Volumes/Server HD/Data/spool!
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com postfix/postfix-script[914]: fatal: no Postfix queue directory /Volumes/Server HD/Data/spool!
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com servermgrd[118]: malformed plist file: missing keys /Library/Server/Network/Config/autoportmap.plist
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerManagerDaemon.bundle' [118] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:51 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [117] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [117] (2,0)
Dec  7 10:04:51 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[21]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [73] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [117] (100000,0)
Dec  7 10:04:52 server.mydomain.com postfix/master[921]: fatal: bind: private/smtp: Permission denied
Dec  7 10:04:53 server com.apple.launchd[1] (org.postfix.master[921]): Exited with code: 1
Dec  7 10:04:53 server com.apple.launchd[1] (org.postfix.master): Throttling respawn: Will start in 8 seconds
Dec  7 10:05:01 server.mydomain.com postfix/master[932]: fatal: bind: private/smtp: Permission denied
Dec  7 10:05:02 server com.apple.launchd[1] (org.postfix.master[932]): Exited with code: 1
Dec  7 10:05:02 server com.apple.launchd[1] (org.postfix.master): Throttling respawn: Will start in 9 seconds
Dec  7 10:05:06 server.mydomain.com log[198]: imap-login: Error: /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/certadmin --get-private-key-passphrase /etc/certificates/server.mydomain.com.89E3F4E6CEE39FB401533135174C1BF0F61E51F9.key.pem: Unable to find matching passphrase in the Keychain
Dec  7 10:05:06 server.mydomain.com log[198]: imap-login: Error: apple_password_callback: /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/certadmin terminated abnormally
Dec  7 10:05:06 server.mydomain.com log[198]: imap-login: Fatal: Couldn't parse private ssl_key
Dec  7 10:05:06 server.mydomain.com dovecotd[124]: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling
Dec  7 10:05:11 server.mydomain.com postfix/master[939]: fatal: bind: private/smtp: Permission denied
Dec  7 10:05:12 server com.apple.launchd[1] (org.postfix.master[939]): Exited with code: 1
Dec  7 10:05:12 server com.apple.launchd[1] (org.postfix.master): Throttling respawn: Will start in 9 seconds
```

Edit: `postconf -n` (as requested):

```
$ postconf -n
biff = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /Library/Server/Mail/Data/mta
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
imap_submit_cred_file = /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/submit.cred
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = _postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10485760
mydomain_fallback = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /Volumes/Server HD/Data/spool
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = _postdrop
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = SSLv2, aNULL, ADH, eNULL
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
use_sacl_cache = yes
```

Permissions on `/private/*` (as requested):

```
admin $ cd /
admin $ ls -l
...
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root  wheel      204 Dec  6 14:01 private
...
admin $ cd private/
server:private admin $ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  128 root  wheel  4352 Dec  7 08:23 etc
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel   102 Dec  6 16:24 tftpboot
drwxrwxrwt   27 root  wheel   918 Dec  7 06:03 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   31 root  wheel  1054 Dec  6 16:24 var
```

Comment: Which postfix version, output of `postconf -n`, permissions on private/*

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is listed in your log

```
Dec  7 10:04:50 server.mydomain.com postfix/postfix-script[912]: fatal: no Postfix queue directory /Volumes/Server HD/Data/spool!
```

Create directory */Volumes/Server HD/Data/spool* and assign postfix permission to it.

Then restart your mail service.

Please keep in mind this MAY NOT solve your postfix problem completely, but at least let you move a step forward.

**2 potential problem to your main.cf**

**(1)** With a clean install Mountain Lion Server, the data spool is usually located at

```
/Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
```

In your /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/main.cf, you may want to change

```
queue_directory = /Volumes/Server HD/Data/spool
```

To

```
queue_directory = /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
```

**(2)** Missing mydestination in main.cf, you may want to add it back

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

Comment: Is this resolved?